# Is it OK to write PHP function on Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have written function on Laravel Blade file. It is working, but I don't know is it ok or not? if it is wrong where should keep php functions.

I wrote top of the blade,

```
function convertMinToHourMin($total_min){
    $hours = 0;
    $min = 0;
    $hours =  intval($total_min/60);
    $min = $total_min%60;
    return $hours.'.'.$min;
}
```

Please someone give advice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it depends on what the function do.

If this function is used only in a specific view, put this function inside that blade file is acceptable.

If this function do somethings that can be used in many places, you should move it to a php file and include it in `start.php` or use composer autoloading.

Comment: If this is a value from a model that needs changing, I would add the function in the model.

Comment: That's correct, if $total_min is one of your Model attribute, you can use [Accessors & Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators), if this is just an utility method, use it as your model static method.